Quarto delete plot files after rendering
The directory for the plot files is generated but once the docx document is rendered the plots and directory disappear.  I have never experienced this before.
Is this an MAC OSX thing? I can't remember it happening on Windows 10.
Quarto 1.5.52
[✓] Checking versions of quarto binary dependencies...
      Pandoc version 3.2.0: OK
      Dart Sass version 1.70.0: OK
      Deno version 1.41.0: OK
      Typst version 0.11.0: OK
[✓] Checking versions of quarto dependencies......OK
[✓] Checking Quarto installation......OK
      Version: 1.5.52
      Path: /Applications/quarto/bin

[✓] Checking tools....................OK
      TinyTeX: (external install)
      Chromium: (not installed)

[✓] Checking LaTeX....................OK
      Using: TinyTex
      Path: /Users/rossd/Library/TinyTeX/bin/universal-darwin
      Version: 2024

[✓] Checking basic markdown render....OK

[✓] Checking Python 3 installation....OK
      Version: 3.9.6
      Path: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3
      Jupyter: (None)

      Jupyter is not available in this Python installation.
      Install with python3 -m pip install jupyter

[✓] Checking R installation...........OK
      Version: 4.4.1
      Path: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources
      LibPaths:
        - /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.4-arm64/Resources/library
      knitr: 1.48
      rmarkdown: 2.27

[✓] Checking Knitr engine render......OK
############ R ###################
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.4.1 (2024-06-14)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20
Running under: macOS Sonoma 14.5

############################## RStudio ##############

RStudio 2024.04.2+764 "Chocolate Cosmos" Release (e4392fc9ddc21961fd1d0efd47484b43f07a4177, 2024-06-05) for macOS
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) RStudio/2024.04.2+764 Chrome/120.0.6099.291 Electron/28.3.1 Safari/537.36, Quarto 1.5.52 (/Applications/quarto/bin/quarto)

I expected the figure plot files to be stored in a directory under the working directory
---
title: "The case of the disappearing graphic files"
author: "RossD"
format: docx
---

## Quarto

Quarto enables you to weave together content and executable code into a finished document. To
learn more about Quarto see <https://quarto.org>.

## Running Code

```{r}
#| label: fig-keepit
#| fig-cap: A simple plot
plot(0:10, runif(11))
```


Sounds like the extract-media option is what you need. Quoting the docs:

Extract images and other media contained in or linked from the source document to the path DIR, creating it if necessary, and adjust the images references in the document so they point to the extracted files. Media are downloaded, read from the file system, or extracted from a binary container (e.g. docx), as needed. The original file paths are used if they are relative paths not containing ... Otherwise filenames are constructed from the SHA1 hash of the contents.

Amending the YAML header with the following should make Quarto preserve all generated graphs in the media folder.
extract-media: media

